# docker-compose run --rm doesn't exit container after command is run

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

docker-compose version 1.8.0. The container is linked to another container. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with why the container isn't exiting

```
mongodb:
  image: 'mongo:3.2'
  ports:
    - '27017:27017'
  environment:
    - AUTH=no

test:
  image: node:6.3.1
  command: node tests/ref-api.js
  working_dir: /opt/runapp
  volumes:
    - ./:/opt/runapp
    - ../webapp/server:/opt/runapp/node_modules/server
    - ../webapp/package/node_modules:/opt/runapp/node_modules/server/node_modules
  links:
    - mongodb
```

Comment: Maybe the Dockerfile will be more useful?

Comment: Not using a Dockerfile. Running `docker-compose run --rm test` in the command line

Comment: I tried to replicate your scenario but I am getting only the mongo container running, which is expected since docker-compose detects it as a dependency and starts it. If I remove the --rm I see the test container stopped after the run as well.

Comment: Are you using `-d` in the command? `--rm` is ignored if you use `-d`.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean by "isn't exiting"? The normal behavior of `docker-compose run` the way you're using it is for the `mongodb` container to remain running until you stop it with `docker-compose stop`.